# How to add rows to a table with missing dates (days), filling in the added rows with the values copied from the rows below?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have table:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([
("2019-01-22", np.nan, np.nan),
("2019-01-25", 10, 15),
("2019-01-28", 200, 260),
("2019-02-03", 3010, 3800),
("2019-02-05", 40109, 45009)],
columns=["date", "col1", "col2"])
```

[image: Table_1]

I need to add new rows to the table where the date (day) is missing. In the added rows, in columns `col1` and `col2`, there must be values copied from the row located below in the table (from rows with more recent dates).

I need to get the following table:

[image: Table2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pandas.to_datetime` and `asfreq`:

```
df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['date'])).drop('date', 1).asfreq('1 d').bfill().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
         date     col1     col2
0  2019-01-22     10.0     15.0
1  2019-01-23     10.0     15.0
2  2019-01-24     10.0     15.0
3  2019-01-25     10.0     15.0
4  2019-01-26    200.0    260.0
5  2019-01-27    200.0    260.0
6  2019-01-28    200.0    260.0
7  2019-01-29   3010.0   3800.0
8  2019-01-30   3010.0   3800.0
9  2019-01-31   3010.0   3800.0
10 2019-02-01   3010.0   3800.0
11 2019-02-02   3010.0   3800.0
12 2019-02-03   3010.0   3800.0
13 2019-02-04  40109.0  45009.0
14 2019-02-05  40109.0  45009.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = df.sort_values("date")
df = df.fillna(method='bfill')
```

Sort the dataframe according to date and fill the nulls with the next non-null values.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([
("2019-01-22", np.nan, np.nan),
("2019-01-25", 10, 15),
("2019-01-28", 200, 260),
("2019-02-03", 3010, 3800),
("2019-02-05", 40109, 45009)],
columns=["date", "col1", "col2"])

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.index = df['date']
df.drop('date',1,inplace=True)

df.resample('D').asfreq().bfill()
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

1. convert date to an actual date obj (was a str)
2. set index to be the date column (because of how resample/bfill works)
3. drop the date column
4. resample dates on a daily bases, backfill missing data
5. reset index so its back to being a regular column